# Rigid Body Physics

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I created my vehicle and added rigid body physics to it. It now moves in an animated fashion when on a plane but it drops at the beginning of the animation and it moves really slowly. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks for any help you may provide.[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it drops, then its possibly not on the floor, or the floor is not a "Passive Rigid Body Object".
If you want to have an easier Live with Rigid-Body, use my add on for that:
It will automatically do many of the needed settings:
https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL47fPMVhRxCcrFPvlo6Tm8-cbiKz_tVJH